# saving data from facebook codeigniter login

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, oauth, facebook-php-sdk

I have a problem in this part of my code, where i want to insert it my model named user_model with a function of checkUser2. How can i insert this data from my database, i have no error but i cannot var_dump the data that i want to insert into my database.

```
 public function facebook_request(){
        $this->load->library('facebook/src/facebook', array('appId' => '1027885817316593', 'secret' => '6db175699897b514bf4881955b2944bb'));
        $this->user = $this->facebook->getUser();
        if ($this->user) {
            $data['user_profile'] = $this->facebook->api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,link,gender,locale,picture');

            // Get logout url of facebook
            $data['logout_url'] = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => base_url() . 'index.php/oauth_login/logout'));
                $data = array(
                    'oauth_provider'=> 'facebook',
                    'oauth_uid'     => $data['user_profile']['id'],
                    'first_name'    => $data['user_profile']['first_name'],
                    'last_name'     => $data['user_profile']['last_name'],
                    'email'         => $data['user_profile']['email'],
                    'gender'        => $data['user_profile']['gender'],
                    'locale'        => $data['user_profile']['locale'],
                    'picture'       => $data['user_profile']['picture']['data']['url'],
                    'link'          => $data['user_profile']['link']
                );
                $userData = $this->user_model->checkUser2($data);

                var_dump($data);
            // Send data to profile page
            $this->load->view('admin/profile.php', $data);


        } 
        else {

            // Store users facebook login url
            $data['login_url'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl();
            $this->load->view('auth/profile.php', $data);
        }
```

with model :

```
 function checkUser2($userData){
    $this->db->insert('tbl_oauth', $userData);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

here is my table screenshot details:
[image]

Comment: means data is successfully inserted in the database, then where is the problem?

Comment: @kishor10d hello thank you for your answer,.. I dont get any errors but i am not sure if my code is really getting what i want. It doesn't save the data from my database.

Comment: check your model function, you are accepting ```$userData``` and trying to insert ```$data```. Also you write ```return``` twice which is not possible.

Comment: @kishor10d thank you sir i'll try this,.. hello sir i edited my question but still nothing to save in my db

Comment: Are you sure that your data and database-fields having same datatype, and also there is no constraint violation while inserting the data? Can you update the question with your table definition.

Comment: @kishor10d hello sir, i updated and put a screenshot on my question, i am wondering, how can i something like i tried var_dump($data) but i can't see the values. where can i see if there is a true values in my data array sir. or how can i see it ?

Comment: do you get $data result before insert or model call?

Comment: You need to provide enumeration set to you oauth_provider column in your table e.g. facebook

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap thank you for your answer sir, i displayed the $data['user_profile'] in my view but i am not sure about the data array that i made to pass within the model.

Comment: @kishor10d hello sir, i've change/updated the oath_provider column with varchar in db.

Comment: Try to print the data first, and make sure that you are getting the expected data from FB. Once data will appear, check the limit of storage in tables.

Comment: @kishor10d hello sir, how can i print my data in controller

Comment: You wrote var_dump already, just try die; after that. It will stop the execution and show your data. Also, why you are using same $data variable again and again. I think it is overwritten.

Comment: @kishor10d ok i'll try it

Comment: @kishor10d is this the way to var_dump and die?                 die(var_dump($datame));

Comment: @JcJohn :  yes man, you can do that. please go through http://php.net/, and get some basic things from there. This is not the right place to ask such a spoon-feeding type things.